# 3D Object in 2D Unity Project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to bring 3D objects into a 2D project that is using the 2D Universal pipeline for rendering? I have some 3D objects I want to bring in to the project I'm working on, but they just get imported as pure white.

Is there a way to import 3D models into a 2D game, and keep the 2D pipeline for lighting? I'l tried a few different shaders, but if they're not pure white they're pink. I would like them to have shading as a 3D object, and still interact with light and rotate on all axis if possible. If it's impossible to use a 3D object, if there was a way to at least have a 2D sprite taken from a 3D object, but still react to light as if it were 3D, that'd work too I suppose.

[3D Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJeIN.jpg)

I've also tried adding 3D lights as well, but to no avail. I'm guessing the issue is because of my 2D lighting renderer, but for the record, this is what this tree looks like in a  [3D project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKCyd.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe this would be helpful https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.1/manual/PrepShader.html

Comment: Well, I have these shaders and the pipeline installed, which I think is why my 3D objects no longer react to lighting. The 2D objects react to light just fine.

Comment: Then you probably need to use 3d light, that would be inefficient in a 2d game so you need to create lots of images from your 3d objects.

Comment: 3D lights don't work either. The object is pure white, with or without a global light.  I'd like the object to move/ stretch somewhat dynamically, the image I showed in this picture is actually just an example, the object I created is a snail that stretches out of his shell after being kicked. I want the direction of his stretching to depend on the direction he's moving.

Comment: How exactly 3D lights don't work on 3D objects? that doesn't sound right

Comment: I'm not sure, they are pure white with no shading. Well, I kinda got it a greyish colour, but it does not react to light. This is with a simple lit material, it looks the same with a lit or an unlit shader. https://imgur.com/a/8ZZVU7g

Comment: you'll have a better chance if you ask it in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ or unity forums

Comment: Okay, I'll try asking in gamedev. I asked multiple other places and got nothing haha. Thanks.

Comment: @Mashimaro7 I am encountering the same problem. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to. I was able to make a custom shader graph and  apply different textures to my objects through that, for some reason it didn't work with any of the default Unity shaders. But no, I wasn't able to get a shader that's, uh, shaded. Probably could make one in shader graph, if I was better at shaders haha.